# Creating a block array from a given array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d array like this

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
```

and I want to create an array, where every entry of the one above fills a whole block of the new array. I.e. if I want 2x2 blocks, I want my new array to look like this

```
B = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
              [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
              [..., ..., ...,],
              [...,  8, 8, 9, 9],
              [...,  8, 8, 9, 9]])
```

I managed to do this by iterating over the arrays and creating a corresponding block for every entry, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A.repeat(2, axis=1).repeat(2, axis=0)
```

First [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) the elements along the first axis to get:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]])
```

Then repeat the elements along the zeroth axis to get:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]])
```

(The order of repetition axes doesn't matter.)

You can change `2`s to the desired block size.